# Issue in AWS S3 PHP SDK Guzzle

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Getting following error:

PHP Warning:  require(Guzzle/Http/Client.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 7

PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'Guzzle/Http/Client.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/home/ec2-user/pear:/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear/Guzzle:./Aws') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 7

my code

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/home/ec2-user/pear');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear/Guzzle');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './Aws');
function my_autoload($class_name) 
{
  $class_name = str_replace("\\","/",$class_name);
  require $class_name. '.php'; 
}
spl_autoload_register('my_autoload');
require '/home/ec2-user/pear/share/pear/Guzzle/Service/Client.php';
require 'Aws/S3/S3Client.php';
```

Can someone answer this?

Thanks
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

This autoloading/including logic doesn't look right at all. If you installed the SDK and Guzzle through PEAR, shouldn't the PEAR directory already be in your PHP path? If so, you only need do:

```
require 'AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar';
```

All of the AWS or Guzzle classes should be autoload-able after that. Also see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: I installed using PEAR and included require Getting error Failed opening required 'AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar'

Comment: It sounds like something is not right about your PEAR configuration. Have you considered NOT using PEAR? We generally recommend using Composer or directly downloading the pre-packaged `aws.phar` to install the SDK. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html.

Comment: Thanks, Now when i run php index.php i am not getting error. But if it is through browser i get error in Apache error logs Failed opening required 'AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar'. Any clues